# how to shares files with windows 8.1 computer?

Tags: windows-8.1, connection, file-sharing, connection-sharing

I have all my files on my brother's PC and now I want to copy them to mine.

Installing a programme didn't help me because it's about 200 GB and takes a long time and sometimes my connection failed.

How can I connect my laptop to my brother's PC with a cable?

Comment: Use an external USB drive.

Comment: [What OS is your brothers PC?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/sharing-files-printers-help#sharing-files-and-printers=windows-7&v1h=win81tab1&v2h=win7tab1&v3h=winvistatab1&v4h=winxptab1)

Comment: I don't have a USB with 200 GB

Comment: You can create an ad hoc network by just connecting both machines with an ethernet cable.